# How to get the Facebook FriendPicker to return the selected friend username?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an invite system that uses the facebook usernames. However the friendpicker provided by facebook only returns GraphUser objects for each selected friend with their name and id. Is there a way to change the FriendPicker to also return the username?

Comment: If its coming from Graph user, you are constrainted only to the data found in that object, however; its likely you'll find enough data to derive it.

Comment: Is there way with the id that I could get to get the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"username" is not a regular field that's passed down from the graph API for friends. The good news is that FriendPickerFragment inherits from PickerFragment, and if you look at the docs for PickerFragment, you'll see that there's a method called [setExtraFields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/PickerFragment#setExtraFields%28Collection%29).

So if you did something like:

```
friendPicker.setExtraFields(Arrays.asList("name", "username"))
```

that should do the trick, and you'll be able to call graphuser.getUserName().

Comment: No luck there either but I think this is the right way to go. I think there is a step missing in this solution. I tried tracing the steps in the api and provided code but I can't find anything.

Comment: Nevermind I got it figured out. I didn't realize that not all facebook users have usernames. That did in fact work. Thanks